# Connecting batteries for an electric scooter

Tags: power-supply, voltage, power

I am trying to replace 12V batteries in an electric scooter and forgot to take a picture of how this was setup before. Should batteries in an electric scooter be connected in series? I.E.: should the wires connect the red to black and then red black again? Any help is appreciated.

[image: image description]

Comment: Google for pictures or a wiring diagram of the same model. We have no idea what that specific scooter needs.

Comment: Dont take my word for it since we dont have enough info, but if it came with the 2 jumpers, then its likely they were in series. Miss-wiring can lead to a fire hazard so double check with the same model of your scooter before plugging it as Passerby said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming it's a 36 V scooter ...

[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fslLcx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>